# How Do I sum "number of rows" correspond to same specific value

Tags: r, sum

Hey I am working on a dataset which include Location and Date. I want to create a new data frame from my original one. New data frame will include Dates (only month) and a number correspond to sum of the same month. For example, If my dataset is like below:

```
USA 2011-01-01
USA 2012-01-01
UK  2010-05-01
UK  2009-05-01
USA 2012-07-01
```

my new data frame will be as below;

```
January  2
May      2
July     1
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
stack(table(format(as.Date(df$V2), "%B")))
```

Produces

```
  values     ind
1      2 January
2      1    July
3      2     May
```

Another option (courtesy Ananda Mahto):

```
stack(table(df$V2))    # here V2 has the dates
```

Produces

```
  values        ind
1      2 2010-05-01
2      2 2011-01-01
3      1 2012-07-01
```

`table` counts the `V2` values (dates); stack makes a data frame out of the result adding a column with the names (`ind`).

Comment: Which work good. Can you check my question again (because I change). and I think I need to apply another function. Thanks.

Comment: appreciated @BrodieG. This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only one last question. when I apply this code the output is starting from April. How can I get an output it will start from January and end in December?

Comment: On the resulting data frame, try something like `df.new[order(as.Date(df.new$ind, format="%B")),]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `aggregate()` function with `length()`:

```
old.data <- data.frame(date = rep(c('a', 'b'), 10))
aggregate(old.data$date, by = list(old.data$date), FUN = length)
```

Comment: Which is perfect. But what if I want to sum only based on months. (So i will not care which year). Do you have any suggestion. I edited my question for my new need.

Comment: Change the `by` to the month, which can be extracted from the date vector as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749666/2196842).