# How to extract Month from date in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using the `lubridate` package and applying the `month` function to extract month from date. I ran the str command on date field and I got

```
Factor w/ 9498 levels "01/01/1979","01/01/1980",..: 5305 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> v1$Date<-month(v1$Date)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Here is an example of my data frame

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6cqWmwsEk20Q2dHblhXZi14Wk0/edit?usp=sharing

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R obtaining month and year from a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749598/r-obtaining-month-and-year-from-a-date)

Comment: This question, the answers that follow, and any resulting code that others will have to support would be much clearer if the month and date differed in the examples, and if the handling of day and month were explicit.  Dates like 01/01/1979 don't convey the necessary meaning when month and day are handled so differently in different contexts.

Comment: After reading in your data, I'm unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, see my comment below.

Comment: So the problem remains... if the OP posts data that doesn't reproduce the error, there is precious little the audience can do other than idle speculation.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`?month` states:

> Date-time must be a POSIXct, POSIXlt, Date, Period, chron, yearmon,
>   yearqtr, zoo, zooreg, timeDate, xts, its, ti, jul, timeSeries, and fts
>   objects.

Your object is a factor, not even a character vector (presumably because of `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`). You have to convert your vector to some datetime class, for instance to `POSIXlt`:

```
library(lubridate)
some_date <- c("01/02/1979", "03/04/1980")
month(as.POSIXlt(some_date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
[1] 2 4
```

There's also a convenience function `dmy`, that can do the same (tip proposed by @Henrik):

```
month(dmy(some_date))
[1] 2 4
```

Going even further, @IShouldBuyABoat gives another hint that dd/mm/yyyy character formats are accepted without any explicit casting:

```
month(some_date)
[1] 2 4
```

For a list of formats, see `?strptime`. You'll find that "standard unambiguous format" stands for

> The default formats follow the rules of the ISO 8601 international
>   standard which expresses a day as "2001-02-28" and a time as
>   "14:01:02" using leading zeroes as here.

Comment: Given that the question was about `lubridate`, you may add `dmy(some_date)` as an alternative to `as.POSIXlt(some_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: `lubridate::month` does not actually need the input to be any of those classes and it will properly read dd/mm/yyyy formats without even having a format string.

Comment: A side-note: it seems that `month` tries to coerce to `as.POSIXlt` and makes some guesses about the format. If dates are in 'dmy' and 'ymd' format, `month` guesses right. Take the first date in the text file from OP, "18/01/1979". This is clearly dmy. `month(as.factor("18/01/1979"))` works. ymd works: `month(as.factor("1979/01/18"))`. `month(as.factor("1979/18/01"))`does not work. So _given_ that the date format in the text file sample seems to be dmy, it might be other dates _not shown_ that are in a non-`month`-guessable format.

Answer (score 71):

**Without the need of an external package:**

if your date is in the following format:

```
myDate = as.POSIXct("2013-01-01")
```

Then to get the month number:

```
format(myDate,"%m")
```

And to get the month string:

```
format(myDate,"%B")
```

Answer (score 19):

You can convert it into date format by-

```
new_date <- as.Date(old_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

from `new_date`, you can get the month by `strftime()`

`month<- strftime(new_date, "%m")`

```
old_date<- "01/01/1979"
new_date<- as.Date(old_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
new_date
#[1] "1979-01-01"
month<- strftime(new_date,"%m")
month
#[1] "01"
year<- strftime(new_date, "%Y")
year
#[1] "1979"
```

Answer (score 0):

For some time now, you can also only rely on the `data.table` package and its `IDate` class plus associated functions. (Check `?as.IDate()`). So, no need to additionally install `lubridate`.

```r
require(data.table)

some_date <- c("01/02/1979", "03/04/1980")
month(as.IDate(some_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) # all data.table functions
```