# How to extract Month and Day from Date in R and convert it as a date type?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am `Rstudio` for my `R` sessions and I have the following `R` codes:

```
d1 <- read.csv("mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

d2 <- d1 %>% 
      mutate(PickUpDate = ymd(PickUpDate))

str(d2$PickUpDate)
```

output of last line of code above is as follows:

```
Date[1:14258], format: "2016-10-21" "2016-07-15" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" ...
```

I need an additional column (let's call it `MthDD`) to the `dataframe` `d2`, which will be the Month and Day of the "`PickUpDate`" column. So, column `MthDD` need to be in the format `mm-dd` but most importantly, it should still be of the `date type`.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:
I have tried the following but it outputs the new column as a character type. I need the column to be of the date type so that I can use it as the x-axis component of a plot.

```
d2$MthDD <- format(as.Date(d2$PickUpDate), "%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` objects do not display as mm-dd. You can create a character string with that representation but it will no longer be of `Date` class -- it will be of `character` class.

If you want an object that displays as mm-dd and still acts like a `Date` object what you can do is create a new S3 subclass of `Date` that displays in the way you want and use that.  Here we create a subclass of `Date` called `mmdd` with an `as.mmdd` generic, an `as.mmdd.Date` method, an `as.Date.mmdd` method and a `format.mmdd` method.  The last one will be used when displaying it.  `mmdd` will inherit methods from `Date` class but you may still need to define additional methods depending on what else you want to do -- you may need to experiment a bit.

```
as.mmdd <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.mmdd")
as.mmdd.Date <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = c("mmdd", "Date"))

as.Date.mmdd <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = "Date")

format.mmdd <- function(x, format = "%m-%d", ...) format(as.Date(x), format = format, ...)

DF <- data.frame(x = as.Date("2018-03-26") + 0:2) # test data

DF2 <- transform(DF, y = as.mmdd(x))
```

giving:

```
> DF2
           x     y
1 2018-03-26 03-26
2 2018-03-27 03-27
3 2018-03-28 03-28

> class(DF2$y)
[1] "mmdd" "Date"

> as.Date(DF2$y)
[1] "2018-03-26" "2018-03-27" "2018-03-28"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
PickUpDate2 <- format(PickUpDate,"%m-%d")
PickUpDate2 <- as.Date(PickUpDate2, "%m-%d")
```

This should work, and you should be able to bind_cols afterwards, or just add it to the data frame right away, as you proposed in the code you provided. So the code should be substituted to be:

```
d2$PickUpDate2 <- format(d2$PickUpDate,"%m-%d")
d2$PickUpDate2 <- as.Date(d2$PickUpDate2, "%m-%d")
```

Comment: You can also take a look on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603847/how-to-extract-month-from-date-in-r

Comment: It replaces all the "year" part of PickUpDate by 2018.
So a date like '2016-05-21' becomes '2018-05-21'