# R only view the first half of the year

Tags: r

I am new to R and have been given a homework to do some basic analysis on a set of data, namely IPO data and the effect of Covid-19 on it. Of course, I have not had any classes in R, so this kind of a "throw him in the pool so he learns to swim" situation.

So I looked up some tutorials, but I just can't figure this out:
I only have to compare the first half of each year (2017-2020), but I just don't know how I can eliminate everything that is not within that time from my dataframe. (Namely, IPOs in August through December.)
How would I do that.

This is the head() of my dataset, at least what R is giving me back

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 16
  ExchangeName CompanyName CurrencyCode ListingVenue ListingDate  Year Month `Domestic/Forei~ `Sector of Acti~
  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>            <chr>           
1 Hong Kong E~ SH Group (~ HKD          MAIN         2017-01-03   2017 Jan   Domestic         Other           
2 Shanghai St~ Central Ch~ CNY          Shanghai St~ 2017-01-03   2017 Jan   Domestic         other           
3 Shanghai St~ Zhejiang H~ CNY          Shanghai St~ 2017-01-03   2017 Jan   Domestic         other           
# ... with 7 more variables: `ISIN/CUSIP/Other` <chr>, Region <chr>, `Country of Incorporation` <chr>, `Market
#   Capitalisation on 1st trading day` <chr>, `Capital raised through IPO (Newly issued shares)` <chr>, `Capital raised
#   through IPO (Already issued shares)` <chr>, `Capital raised through IPO (Total)` <chr>
```

thanks for any help in advance. I am really lost on this

Comment: obviously i mean july through december, sorry for the mixup

Comment: Exactly what is the question?  Are you trying to extract all January-June rows into one data frame and all July to December rows into a second data frame?  If that is the question then `is_first_half <- format(as.Date(DF$ListingDate), "%m") <= "06"; 
DF[is_first_half, ];
DF[!is_first_half, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd transform your `ListingDate` into a `POSIXct` object (this is just a way to store dates and times in their own format instead of text) and select the first semester. Using the package `ludibriate`, you can do this (I got inspiration from [this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603847/how-to-extract-month-from-date-in-r)

```
data <- data[semester(as.POSIXct(data$ListingDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) == 1,]
```

Note that what I did was selecting the rows that were identified by `semester()` (this is the part from `ludibriate`) as being in the first semester, after having converted your character string into a date with `as.POSIXct`. Every part of this could have been done diferently; for instance, you could use `ymd()` instead of `as.POSIXct(..., format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. Actually, I'm pretty sure it's better to use `ymd()`, which is also from`ludibriate`, just because it's simpler. I just didn't put in my main answer because I'm not used to it, but if you want to, do it:

```
data <- data[semester(ymd(data$ListingDate)) == 1,]
```