# How to add the current date into a string in R?

Tags: r, string, concatenation, data-manipulation

I know that Sys.Date() returns the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I have a script that is saving a dataset that has just been manipulated:

```
write.xlsx(DTAX, "C:\\User\\Me\\Documents\\File Name.xlsx")
```

I would like to include the date in that file name as it's saved, though ....

This is what I have so far:

```
write.xlsx(DTAX, paste("C:\\User\\Me\\Documents\\File Name.xlsx", Sys.Date(), " .xlsx"))
```

Which returns:
`File Name 2023-10-26` as the name of the file.

What I would **like** to have is the following:
`File Name 10.16.23`

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of regex, just a problem you have in `R`. Here's an article on [Date Formats in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/date-formats-in-r/) that should help. Using in-built functions is ALWAYS better.

Comment: [Extracting months from a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603847/how-to-extract-month-from-date-in-r) might also be of use

Comment: See the `format()` function.  You want something like: `format(Sys.Date(), "%m.%d.%y")`

Comment: "*I know that Sys.Date() returns the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format.*" - To be clear `Sys.Date()` returns an object of class 'Date' which stores the number of days since 1970-01-01 - see `as.integer(Sys.Date())` , which is printed to the screen as "YYYY-MM-DD" by default because that is what `print.Date` and `format.Date` specify should be done. As others have mentioned, you need to manually override the default `format` function to get what you want.

Comment: Also your current code, `paste("C:\\User\\Me\\Documents\\File Name.xlsx", Sys.Date(), " .xlsx")` will return undesirable results (ie, two ".xlsx" extensions in the filename - "...\\File Name.xlsx 2023-10-16  .xlsx" - you want `paste0("C:\\User\\Me\\Documents\\File Name_", format(Sys.Date(), "%m.%d.%y"), ".xlsx")`