# Aggregate count of timeseries values which exceed threshold, by year-month

Tags: r, aggregate, threshold

I am now learning R and using the SEAS package to help me with some calculation in  R and data is the same format as SEAS package likes. It is a time series

```
require(seas)
data(mscdata)
dat.int <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
```

the heading of the data and it is 20 years of data

```
  year yday  date t_max t_min t_mean rain snow precip
```

However, I now need to calculate the number of days in each month rainfall is >= 1.0mm . So at the end of it. I would have two columns ( each month in each year and total # of days in each month rainfall>= 1.0mm )

I'm not certain how to write this code and any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Lam

Comment: Post some reproducible R code using `dput(yourdataframe)`. *"data is the same format as SEAS package likes"* is not acceptable.

Comment: Hi there,, i am not sure what you are asking me..but i edited ..so hope it makes better sense.. this is my first attempt programming..so please forgive me if not correct in expressing things the right way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I now need to calculate the number of days in each month rainfall is >= 1.0mm. So at the end of it. I would have two columns ( each month in each year and total # of days in each month rainfall>= 1.0mm )

1) So dat.int$date is a Date object. First step is you need to create a new column `dat.int$yearmon` extracting the year-month, e.g. using `zoo::yearmon`
[Extract month and year from a zoo::yearmon object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749598/r-obtaining-month-and-year-from-a-date)

```
require(zoo)
dat.int$yearmon <- as.yearmon(dat.int$date, "%b %y")
```

2) Second, you need to do a **summarize** operation (recommend you use plyr or the newer dplyr) on `rain>=1.0` aggregated by yearmon. Let's name our resulting column *rainy_days*.

If you want to store rainy_days column back into the `dat.int` dataframe, you use a `transform` instead of a `summarize`:

```
ddply(dat.int, .(yearmon), transform, rainy_days=sum(rain >= 1.0) )
```

or else if you really just want a new summary dataframe:

```
require(plyr)
rainydays_by_yearmon <- ddply(dat.int, .(yearmon), summarize, rainy_days=sum(rain >= 1.0) )
print.data.frame(rainydays_by_yearmon)

     yearmon rainy_days
1   Jan 1975         14
2   Feb 1975         12
3   Mar 1975         13
4   Apr 1975          6
5   May 1975          6
6   Jun 1975          5
...
355 Jul 2004          3
356 Aug 2004          7
357 Oct 2004         14
358 Nov 2004         16
359 Dec 2004         19
```

Note: you can do the above with plain old R, without using `zoo` or `plyr/dplyr` packages. But might as well teach you nicer, more scalable, maintainable code idioms.

Comment: Hi I have another question of this dataset.. I am trying to subset the data by months ( eg i want all Jan and its raindays together) I tried this months <- subset(rainydays_by_yearmon, month == 1 ) but is not working .. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As in "all Januaries, across all years"? Then you'll want a 'month' column; read `Date, zoo` packages and SO to get the month from your Date object.

Comment: You need to create another new column called 'month'.

Comment: I tried the column name month, used the code above,  but I still got   blank again ..  1] month      rainy_days
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).

Comment: There *is* no column 'month', currently. You need to **create** one. Like I said three times now. `dat.int <- youfigureoutwhatfunctiontouse((dat.int$date, maybeanotherarg)`

Comment: thanks perhaps my English was bad, but I did had a column name month and tried the my code above and it didn't work. I am sorry for the inconvenience I caused you. thanks for your time

Comment: If we need to see your new code, post a totally new question. (Link it here)