# Count number of month per year under a threshold

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I would to know per **harvestYear**, the number of **month** where **vhi** falls below 40.

example: for year 1982=:3; year 1983= 3

I would like to keep the dataset as it is. Just to add an additional column.

following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473724/aggregate-count-of-timeseries-values-which-exceed-threshold-by-year-month), I have tried this:

```
require(zoo)
df2$yearmon <- as.yearmon(paste(df2$harvestYear, df2$Month), "%Y %m")

df2= ddply(df2, .(yearmon), transform, drought_months=sum(vhi <= 40) )
```

Then I would sum the number of month by grouping. But it does not work.

```
df3= df2 %>%
      group_by(gid, country, xcoord, ycoord, harvestYear, vhi) %>%
      summarise(drought.vhi.month = sum(drought_months))%>%
      ungroup()
```

Dataset:

```
structure(list(gid = c(100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 
100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 104078L, 104078L, 
104078L, 104078L, 104078L, 104078L, 104078L, 104078L, 104078L, 
104078L, 104078L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 
115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L, 115615L), country = c("Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"
), xcoord = c("13.75", "13.75", "13.75", "13.75", "13.75", "13.75", 
"13.75", "13.75", "13.75", "13.75", "18.75", "18.75", "18.75", 
"18.75", "18.75", "18.75", "18.75", "18.75", "18.75", "18.75", 
"18.75", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25", 
"27.25", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25", "27.25"), ycoord = c("-20.25", 
"-20.25", "-20.25", "-20.25", "-20.25", "-20.25", "-20.25", "-20.25", 
"-20.25", "-20.25", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", 
"-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-17.75", "-9.75", 
"-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75", 
"-9.75", "-9.75", "-9.75"), Time = structure(c(4352, 4383, 4717, 
4414, 4442, 4473, 4748, 5082, 4779, 4807, 9862, 10135, 10166, 
10196, 9893, 9921, 9952, 10105, 10227, 10500, 10531, 13057, 13088, 
13118, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 13422, 13453, 13483
), class = "Date"), harvestYear = c(1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1982L, 
1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1983L, 1983L, 1997L, 1998L, 1998L, 
1998L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1998L, 1998L, 1999L, 1999L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L), Month = c(12L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), vhi = c("51.0890450353229", 
"32.441240310669", "40.847339630127", "21.9409523010254", "23.7816608428955", 
"46.6207218170166", "23.5423679351807", "42.2399349212647", "19.0511212348938", 
"10.1214292049408", "59.2775287628174", "68.3184223175049", "63.1654891967773", 
"46.8237014770508", "66.5376491546631", "68.1310760498047", "70.3945808410645", 
"70.0717346191406", "38.8603992462158", "42.2310523986816", "47.7076560974121", 
"38.2882362365723", "32.5415182113648", "36.3100366592407", "48.1315612792969", 
"49.0768402099609", "52.1510925292969", "53.8123741149902", "50.4373531341553", 
"51.5549461364746", "51.573205947876", "46.0322494506836")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 40000L, 40001L, 40002L, 
40003L, 40004L, 40005L, 40006L, 40007L, 40008L, 40009L, 40010L, 
200000L, 200001L, 200002L, 200003L, 200004L, 200005L, 200006L, 
200007L, 200008L, 200009L, 200010L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 drougth month (`vhi <= 40`) in the year 1982. Also the value in `vhi` is character so that needs to be changed to numeric first.

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(vhi = as.numeric(vhi)) %>%
  filter(harvestYear == 1982)

#     gid country xcoord ycoord       Time harvestYear Month      vhi
#1 100468 Namibia  13.75 -20.25 1981-12-01        1982    12 51.08905
#2 100468 Namibia  13.75 -20.25 1982-01-01        1982     1 32.44124
#3 100468 Namibia  13.75 -20.25 1982-02-01        1982     2 21.94095
#4 100468 Namibia  13.75 -20.25 1982-03-01        1982     3 23.78166
#5 100468 Namibia  13.75 -20.25 1982-04-01        1982     4 46.62072
```

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(vhi = as.numeric(vhi)) %>%
  group_by(harvestYear) %>%
  mutate(drought_months = sum(vhi <= 40))

#     gid country xcoord ycoord Time       harvestYear Month   vhi drought_months
#    <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <date>           <int> <int> <dbl>          <int>
# 1 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1981-12-01        1982    12  51.1             3
# 2 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1982-01-01        1982     1  32.4             3
# 3 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1982-12-01        1983    12  40.8             3
# 4 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1982-02-01        1982     2  21.9             3
# 5 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1982-03-01        1982     3  23.8             3
# 6 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1982-04-01        1982     4  46.6             3
# 7 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1983-01-01        1983     1  23.5             3
# 8 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1983-12-01        1984    12  42.2             0
# 9 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1983-02-01        1983     2  19.1             3
#10 100468 Namibia 13.75  -20.25 1983-03-01        1983     3  10.1             3
# … with 22 more rows
```

Comment: My bad for year 1982, wrong typing. regarding the results, I don't know why but I get 10 instead of 3 for all the rows..

Comment: Ohh, that might be because you also have `plyr` loaded which also has `mutate` function. Try using `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Coffee bought :)