# Faster method to extract year in a big file

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 5GB file (19M rows and 16 columns) that I am working on. One of the fields in this file is in YearQtr format. Example 2014Q1. I followed [Extract year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568070/extract-year-from-date) thread to extract year information as:

```
library(zoo)
x <- "2014Q1"
d <- as.factor(format(as.yearqtr(x), "%Y"))
```

While this works, but because I have about 19M rows, it takes forever for RStudio to process this. For instance, it takes about 45 seconds for `fread` to read the files, but 10 minutes to extract the year! Is there anyway I can make this work faster? I'd appreciate any thoughts. I even tried `as.Date()` but there was no improvement. Any thoughts?

Comment: `substr(date,1,4)`? (never name your variables after a function)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus - so, I ran substr(date,1,4), and it was fast (i.e. took about a minute), but the conversion of year to `factor` takes a lot of time. Do you know whether there is any way I can expedite creating factors? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For 100 million observations, I get a time of about 3 seconds: `x = sample(as.character(1900:2000), 1e8, replace = TRUE); system.time(as.factor(x))`. By the way, if you're using data.table, it is possibly more efficient to use `substr` by groups (since you will have many more obs than years).

Comment: @Frank. This is interesting. I am not sure but I tried to save my data in .RData, and the total size is 406MB (disk space) (after clearing all variables and only keeping the data frame). When I ran your query in a fresh session, I was also able to run the query in about 4 seconds, same as yours. Do you need any information about my system?

Comment: Hm, I don't think I need system info, nor that I'd be savvy enough to know what to do with it :) If you can find a way to build a reproducible example, though, you could edit it into the question.

Comment: You could provide the random dummy data of your size, it would help us to address your problem - and provide an answer. You may want to check internal (and local) function in data.table [`as_factor`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/77956204cc267c3b0581db9db6b970b9a19d7253/R/fread.R#L157), which uses fast data.table ordering to create factor, it should speed up your code, you need to copy it and use `data.table:::forderv`. Feel free to self-answer your question with the code, and if possible timings.

Comment: @jangorecki Sure, I can provide dummy data. I am an absolute beginner in R and have only been using "actively" for about 3 weeks. Do you mind pointing me to how I can pull dummy data? I googled "dummy data in R" and found a bunch of books for dummies. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: For making dummy data, see [*"How to make a great R reproducible example"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)