# Extracting year from dates in a column

Tags: r

I'm really new to R!

I have the following column *CMPLNT_FR_DT* in a dataset called *crimedata*

```
CMPLNT_FR_DT
12/31/2015
01/23/2009
10/04/2010
05/31/2015
```

I need to change the column values so that the dates only include the years, like:

```
CMPLNT_FR_DT
2015
2009
2010
2015
```

I tried solutions from 
[Extract year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568070/extract-year-from-date)

but my error returns as

```
format(as.Date(df$CMPLNT_FR_DT, format="%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y")

Error in df$CMPLNT_FR_DT : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: `format(as.Date('12/31/2015', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y')` works fine

Comment: @Sotos I'm aware that that might work, however I'm trying to format the whole column

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Try this `df <- read.table(text = 'CMPLNT_FR_DT 12/31/2015 01/23/2009 10/04/2010 05/31/2015', h=T); format(as.Date(df$CMPLNT_FR_DT, format = '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a dataset called `crimedata` and use `df` instead (when `df` is not defined as a variable, i.e. `"df" %in% ls()` returns `[1] FALSE`), you would get the error `Error in df$CMPLNT_FR_DT : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. This is because `df()` is a function from the `stats` package (which is why it might not be good practice to use `df` as a variable name).

If you change it to `format(as.Date(crimedata$CMPLNT_FR_DT, format="%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y")` it will work.

There is another solution, using the package `lubridate`, which returns the year as numeric, which might be useful:

```
library(lubridate)
year(as.Date(crimedata$CMPLNT_FR_DT, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I now understand what I was doing wrong. Is there any way I could fix the whole column values according to the years in the original dataset?

Comment: Are you sure? Try `df <- read.table(text = 'CMPLNT_FR_DT
12/31/2015
01/23/2009
10/04/2010
05/31/2015', h=T); format(as.Date(df$CMPLNT_FR_DT, format = '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y')`

Comment: i have added a line to further explain my point. of course, if you have a dataframe `df` defined, it would work. However, the error comes from the fact that `df` is not defined.

Comment: If It is not defined then why would they call it? Doesn't make sense. The way the question is asked shows that the data framed was named `df`.

Comment: in the question is says: 'I have the following column CMPLNT_FR_DT in a dataset called crimedata'.

Comment: With `lubridate` you can also write `year(mdy(crimedata$CMPLNT_FR_DT))`