# Add column to display period of time, based on start year and end year

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns

I have a data.table that looks like this

```
CUSTOMER_ID START_DATE  END_DATE        COUNTRY
1           2006-11-10  2010-10-25      USA
2           2006-11-10  2018-09-29      FRANCE
3           2017-08-23  2018-09-29      CHINA
4           2007-01-30  2018-09-29      JAPAN
5           2007-01-30  2018-09-29      COLOMBIA
6           2007-01-30  2017-01-30      BRAZIL
7           2007-01-30  2017-01-30      USA
8           2012-03-15  2018-09-29      USA
9           2012-03-15  2018-09-29      CHINA
10          2006-11-10  2015-11-06      CHINA
```

With these data I'd like to do the following:

1. Calculate the difference in years between two dates
2. Based on the calculated number of years, I want to create a new column "PERIOD", to display each period each customer has been active, using the start and end year in the START_DATE and END_DATE columns. The end result should be something like this:

   ```
     ID    PERIOD  COUNTRY
     1   2006-2007 USA
     1   2007-2008 USA
     1   2008-2009 USA
     1   2009-2010 USA
     2   2006-2007 FRANCE
     2   2007-2008 FRANCE
     2   2008-2009 FRANCE
     2   2009-2010 FRANCE
     2   2010-2011 FRANCE
     2   2011-2012 FRANCE
     2   2012-2013 FRANCE
     2   2013-2014 FRANCE
     2   2014-2015 FRANCE
     2   2015-2016 FRANCE
     2   2016-2017 FRANCE
     2   2017-2018 FRANCE
     3   2017-2018 CHINA
     3   2018-     CHINA
   ```

So far, I've been able to get to number 1 above (calculate the difference in years between the START_DATE and the END_DATE):

```
date_cols <- c("START_DATE", "END_DATE")

DT[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, anytime::anydate), .SDcols = date_cols]

DT[,YEARS_ACTIVE:= ceiling(as.numeric(END_DATE-START_DATE)/365)]
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: [Extract year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568070/extract-year-from-date) + [Expand ranges defined by “from” and “to” columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns) + maybe a little bit of `shift` and `paste`.